# Insert using subquery by adding dates between two dates based on days [oracle 11g]

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g, insert, subquery

This is `presentation` table:

```
ID     PRESENTATIONDAY         PRESENTATIONSTART       PRESENTATIONEND        PRESENTATIONSTARTDATE             PRESENTATIONENDDATE 
622         Monday                   12:00:00              02:00:00              01-05-2016                            04-06-2016 
623        Tuesday                   12:00:00              02:00:00              01-05-2016                            04-06-2016 
624        Wednesday                 08:00:00              10:00:00              01-05-2016                            04-06-2016 
625        Thursday                  10:00:00              12:00:00              01-05-2016                            04-06-2016
```

I would like to insert `availabledate` in `schedule` table. This is my current query :

```
insert into SCHEDULE (studentID,studentName,projectTitle,supervisorID,    
                      supervisorName,examinerID,examinerName,exavailableID,
                     availableday,availablestart,availableend,
                     availabledate) //PROBLEM STARTS HERE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?));
```

The value `availabledate` are retrieved based on the `exavailableID` 
. For example, if `exavailableID` = 2, the `availableday` = Monday, `availablestart`= 12pm, `availableend` = 2pm.

The dates will only be chosen only between `PRESENTATIONSTARTDATE` to `PRESENTATIONENDDATE` from `presentation` table.

In `presentation` table, it will match `PRESENTATIONDAY`, `PRESENTATIONDATESTART` and `PRESENTATIONDATEEND` with `availableday`, `availablestart` and `availableend` to get a list of all possible dates.

This is the query to get list of all possible dates based on particular days:

```
select 
  A.PRESENTATIONID,
  A.PRESENTATIONDAY,
  A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta LIST_DATE
from 
  PRESENTATION A, 
  (
     select level-1 as delta 
     from dual 
     connect by level-1 <= (
       select max(PRESENTATIONDATEEND- PRESENTATIONDATESTART) from PRESENTATION
     )
  )
where A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta <= A.PRESENTATIONDATEEND
and
  a.presentationday = trim(to_char(A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta, 'Day'))
order by 1,2,3;
```

This query result is:

```
622 Monday  02-05-2016 12:00:00
...
622 Monday  30-05-2016 12:00:00
623 Tuesday 03-05-2016 12:00:00
...
623 Tuesday 31-05-2016 12:00:00
624 Wednesday   04-05-2016 12:00:00
...
624 Wednesday   01-06-2016 12:00:00
625 Thursday    05-05-2016 12:00:00
...
625 Thursday    02-06-2016 12:00:00
```

It will automatically assign dates from the `SELECT` query to be inserted in `schedule` table. However, each date can be used only 4 times. Once it reached 4 times, it will proceed to next date. For example, if Monday, '02-05-2016' to '09-05-2016'

How can I corporate these two queries (`INSERT` and `SELECT`) to have a result like this:

```
  StudentName  projectTitle SupervisorID ExaminerID  availableday    availablestart       availableend      availabledate
        abc         Hello     1024       1001            MONDAY         12.00pm                2.00pm         02-05-2016
        def         Hi        1024       1001            MONDAY         12.00pm                2.00pm         02-05-2016
        ghi         Hey       1002       1004            MONDAY         12.00pm                2.00pm         02-05-2016
        xxx         hhh       1020       1011            MONDAY         12.00pm                2.00pm         02-05-2016
        jkl         hhh       1027       1010            MONDAY         12.00pm                2.00pm         09-05-2016 
        try         ttt       1001       1011            MONDAY         12.00pm                2.00pm         09-05-2016
        654         bbb       1007       1012            MONDAY         12.00pm                2.00pm         09-05-2016
        gyg         888       1027       1051            MONDAY         12.00pm                2.00pm         09-05-2016
        yyi         333       1004       1022           TUESDAY         12.00pm                2.00pm         03-05-2016
        fff         111       1027       1041           TUESDAY          ..
        ggg         222       1032       1007           TUESDAY          ..    ..                       ..               ..
        hhh         444       1007       1001           TUESDAY         12.00pm                2.00pm         03-05-2016


         and so on :)
```

In short, I would like to use the list of dates from `presentation` table based on the day, start time and end time to insertion query where each date will only used 4 times. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this kind of syntax works with oracle (and have no good way to check), but changing the select part of insert like this may or may not work.

```
select 
  A.PRESENTATIONID,
  A.PRESENTATIONDAY,
  A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta LIST_DATE
from 
  PRESENTATION A, 
  (
     select level-1 as delta 
     from dual 
     connect by level-1 <= (
       select max(PRESENTATIONDATEEND - PRESENTATIONDATESTART) from PRESENTATION
     )
  ),
  --MIGHT NEED ADDITIONAL LOGIC FOR THE EXAVAILABLEID COMPARISON
  (SELECT count(S.*) as counter FROM SCHEDULE S WHERE S.EXAVAILABLEID=A.ID) C
where A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta <= A.PRESENTATIONDATEEND
and
  a.presentationday = trim(to_char(A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta, 'Day'))
and 
  C.counter<4
order by 1,2,3;
```

EDIT: Changed the operator. Had >= before. Placed teh WHERE check at the right place. Deleted aliases.

EDIT2: changed the syntax to where the counter select statement is a part of the from clause.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Dahamsta :) how does this query helped me to only use the date 4 times only each?

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood the problem. I get it now. What you might do is create a trigger before updates that checks and throws an error when there if there are already four rows with the presentation ID in the schedule table.

Comment: I dont understand the trigger cascade part... any general example at least?

Comment: This is quite complex!! Actually, `exavailableID` is not from `presentationID`... `exavailableID` is retrieved from another table. So I just match them with day, start time and end time because the IDs are not similar.. However, I tried your query with some adjustments, I got an error : `ORA-04089: cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS`

Comment: If you use a specific schema, you should define the trigger as CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_schedule
   before INSERT ON "your schema".schedule. Also this will only stop the insertion of the fifth element with the same presentation ID with a raised error.

Comment: Hmmmm is there any other solution by using only `select` statement and truncate?

Comment: Yeah this solution I have will most likely not work for you. The problem is outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377346/why-cannot-i-create-triggers-on-objects-owned-by-sys. I presume your current schema is the default system schema. Gonna look into truncate.

Comment: I have this idea... But Idk how to execute it. Something like : `trunc(( somevariables - 1) / 4), availabledate`. Maybe `partition by` clause...

Comment: Hmm thank you!!! Ill try to modify your query based on my requirements. I think I understand what you are trying to do :D Thank you again!

Comment: Hello, I tried the query again.. the first part of the query, works well. the second part  (`(SELECT count(S.*)...`)of the query have error :` invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification`